# Android avoid image scalling in Imageview for Image Mapping like Html

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, scale, imagemap

Hi Am trying to implement image mapping as like html in android. For that i referred this [project](https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap). Its work good when i access the image from **drawable-nodpi** folder. But when i access from other **drawable** folder the image get **scaled** as per the android concepts. Here i used drawable folder for checking purpose only. Actually i get image from back end service.

I also tried with **bitmap** by setting the **no density**.

```
Bitmap bm;
bm=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blueprint);
bm.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);
mImageMap.setImageBitmap(bm); //mImageMap is customized view which extends Imageview
```

But it's not working. Am also tried as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13182730/1790537). Its not working.Is there any way to load image to image view without scaling?
[image: IMAGE_FROM_drawable-nodpi][image]

Comment: have you checked this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296465/how-do-i-prevent-scaling-in-android-imageview

Comment: @samara yes i did. No use. still it be same as like before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` with the orignal mesaures of the picture..

```
int width = orignal bitmap width
int height = orignal bitmap height
Bitmap bm;
bm = getBitmap... from network
bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,width,height,true);
```

this will create a image scaled properly and just place it in the ImageView.

Comment: work well. Thank you. Do you know any alternate for this without mentioning image width and height?

Comment: since the image your working is bigger it will always scale the image to the screen.... can you use maybe a small image from the server?

Comment: No am using 800x600(approx) image in server. am developing this for both android phone and tablet and iphone.